# Delete all the pods created by applying Helm2.13.1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to Helm. I'm trying to deploy a simple server on the master node. When I do helm install and see the details using the command kubectl get po,svc I see lot of pods created other than the pods I intend to deploy.So, My precise questions are:

1. Why so many pods got created?
2. How do I delete all those pods?
   Below is the output of the command kubectl get po,svc:

NAME    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE

pod/altered-quoll-stx-sdo-chart-6446644994-57n7k            1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/austere-garfish-stx-sdo-chart-5b65d8ccb7-jjxfh          1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/bald-hyena-stx-sdo-chart-9b666c998-zcfwr                1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/cantankerous-pronghorn-stx-sdo-chart-65f5699cdc-5fkf9   1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/crusty-unicorn-stx-sdo-chart-7bdcc67546-6d295           1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/exiled-puffin-stx-sdo-chart-679b78ccc5-n68fg            1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/fantastic-waterbuffalo-stx-sdo-chart-7ddd7b54df-p78h7   1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/gangly-quail-stx-sdo-chart-75b9dd49b-rbsgq              1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/giddy-pig-stx-sdo-chart-5d86844569-5v8nn                1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/hazy-indri-stx-sdo-chart-65d4c96f46-zmvm2               1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/interested-macaw-stx-sdo-chart-6bb7874bbd-k9nnf         1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/jaundiced-orangutan-stx-sdo-chart-5699d9b44b-6fpk9      1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/kindred-nightingale-stx-sdo-chart-5cf95c4d97-zpqln      1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/kissing-snail-stx-sdo-chart-854d848649-54m9w            1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/lazy-tiger-stx-sdo-chart-568fbb8d65-gr6w7               1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/nonexistent-octopus-stx-sdo-chart-5f8f6c7ff8-9l7sm      1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/odd-boxer-stx-sdo-chart-6f5b9679cc-5stk7                1/1     Running            1          15h

pod/orderly-chicken-stx-sdo-chart-7889b64856-rmq7j          1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/redis-697fb49877-x5hr6                                  1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/rv.deploy-6bbffc7975-tf5z4                              1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   93         30h

pod/sartorial-eagle-stx-sdo-chart-767d786685-ct7mf          1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/sullen-gnat-stx-sdo-chart-579fdb7df7-4z67w              1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/undercooked-cow-stx-sdo-chart-67875cc5c6-mwvb7          1/1     Running            0          25m

pod/wise-quoll-stx-sdo-chart-5db8c766c9-mhq8v               1/1     Running            0          21m

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command `helm ls` to see all the deployed helm releases in your cluster.
To remove the release (and every resource it created, including the pods), run: `helm delete RELEASE_NAME --purge`.

If you want to delete all the pods in your namespace without your Helm release (I DON'T think this is what you're looking for), you can run: `kubectl delete pods --all`.

On a side note, if you're new to Helm, consider starting with Helm v3 since it has many improvements, and specially because the migration from v2 to v3 can become cumbersome, and if you can avoid it - you should.